# How do you ask a program to repeat when you want to limit your string to a specific input?

Tags: java

I've currently started with Java, so I am still fairly new and learning. I wanted to ask more of a general question. So I currently have written a program but I just don't know how to implement a feature where if a you enter a string, say more than 50, and it will tell you to try again. My code simplified is as follows:

```
           class {
                main {
                       declared variables;
                       do {
                         
                         accept and read user string
                         convert string to lowercase
                         for loop for displaying vowels
                         for loop for displaying number of vowels in string
                         if else statements of where each index of where each vowel first appeared

                       } while;
                 }
            }
```

Please help me in any way possible. Thank you.

Comment: You need to create while loop and break of it when user entered correct input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a length check, you can implement your

```
accept and read user string
```

pseudocode as

```
do {
    prompt user for input
    read user string // blocking call

    if string passes validation
        break out of this loop
    else
        print try again message
} while true

// string accepted
convert string to lowercase
```